Git submodule autoupdate to latest branch
I have added a submodule with a following config
[submodule "common"]
    path = common
    url = https://gitlab.io/public/common
    branch = master

But when I make a new commit in the submodule's repo, a fresh clone of the repo doesn't point to that new commmit. It points to the previous one. So to update, I still need to manually checkout/pull commit.
What I want to achieve is that if a repo is cloned a new it will automatically take in the latest commit from the master branch. Is this possible?

Update the submodule, commit the update in the superproject, push the superproject; next clone of the superproject will point to the currently latest commit of the submodule… until the submodule changes again. Alas, no way around that, the superproject remembers the commit for the submodule, changing that commit and pushing the superproject is the only way.
